# c# events: on which thread

Tags: c#, events, thread-safety

pseudo-code:

```
class A
{
    Dictionary<string, object> dic = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public Do()
    {
        some_a.SomeEvent += (s, e) =>
                 {
                     dic["some_string"] = new object();
                 };   
         dic["some_other_string"] = new object();
    }
}
```

Is this safe? It would be if both dictionary operations were on single same thread. So are they?

**EDIT** In my situation event is fired in the same thread as `Do`, so it's safe.

Comment: well, it depends on what thread your "some_a" object invokes the SomeEvent Handler. if yes, assume it´s safe, otherwise, no.

Comment: You can detect which thread you are running on by using something like 
Console.Write(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An event happens (*usually*) on the thread that invokes the event. So we can't actually comment completely since you don't show the code that causes the event to be invoked!

Strictly speaking, the event could be on any thread - either because a random thread is calling `OnSomeEvent` (or whatever the trigger is), or if the `OnSomeEvent` implementation chooses to use `BeginInvoke` for some reason, but this is unlikely.

Ultimately, it comes down to: is there a reason to think multiple threads are involved in this code.

But: what absolutely **is not the case**: no, there is nothing that will *make* that event automatically happen on the thread that subscribes it. An event subscription is just an object+method pair; no thread is nominated in the subscription.

Answer (score 3):

The code inside the event handler will execute on the thread the event is raised on.

```
class AsyncWorker
{
    public void BeginWork()
    {
        new TaskFactory().StartNew(() => RaiseMyEvent());
    }

    public event EventHandler MyEvent;

    private void RaiseMyEvent()
    {
        var myEvent = MyEvent;
        if(myEvent != null)
            myEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

var worker = new AsyncWorker();
worker.MyEvent += (s, e) =>
                  {
                      /* I will be executed on the thread
                         started by the TaskFactory */
                  };
worker.BeginWork();
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you specifically start the event handler in a different thread, both operations will indeed run on the same thread (assuming a single threaded application).